# How to use counter in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying use a counter in my application to saving the likes.
This is my code at the moment

```
likevideo(String id, double _rating, String uidofuploadeduser) async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

    DocumentSnapshot doc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(id).get();
    if (!doc.data()['likes'].contains(uid)) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(id).update({
        'likes': FieldValue.arrayUnion([uid]),
      });

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('videos')
          .doc(id)
          .collection("uservotes")
          .doc(uid)
          .set({
        'rating': _rating,
        
        
      });
    }
  }
```

So as you can see I checking first if the user dont exist in the array in that case I let him liked and if he already exist in the array I let him dislike. thats my method

```
  dislike(String id, double _rating) async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot doc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(id).get();
    if (doc.data()['likes'].contains(uid)) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').doc(id).update({
        'likes': FieldValue.arrayRemove([uid]),
      });
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('videos')
          .doc(id)
          .collection("uservotes")
          .doc(uid)
          .delete();
    }
```

So the problem is I often need the length of the array and because of that instead of always reading each document I wanna use a counter function but actually have no idea how to do that . So hope anyone can help . If you need more information please leave a comment .

Heres for exmaple I using it

```
Icon(
                                                  Icons.star,
                                                  size: 37,
                                                  color: FirebaseFirestore
                                                              .instance
                                                              .collection(
                                                                  "videos")
                                                              .doc(videos
                                                                  .data()['id'])
                                                              .collection(
                                                                  "uservotes")
                                                              .doc(uid)!=
                                                          null
                                                      ? Colors.yellow
                                                      : Colors.white,
                                                ),
```

Ant at the moment the list is empty so no user votes but the star is yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to do that with cloud functions. Othervise you would give everyone the access to change the total amount of likes ;) Just set a firestore trigger when someone adds or removes a like. I woul also recommend to store each like as a collection document and not in an array because as you mentioned you would need the whole array (all likes) to check if someone likes something. If you store it under `likes/${userUid}` you just check if that path exists. It would minimise your reads drasticaly.

With firestore you can do it very easy with the `increment` FieldValue call:

```js
  const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

    await db
      .doc(`user_posts/${postAuthorUid}/posts/${postUid}`)
      .set({ comments: increment }, { merge: true });
```

And for a dislike just change `1` to `-1`.

This is how your whole `index.js` file in the `functions` folder would look like:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onLikeCreated = functions.firestore
  .document(`videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{voteUid}`)
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const { videoUid } = context.params;
    const { rating = 0 } = snap.data();

    const incrementLikes = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
    const incrementRating = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(rating);

    return db
      .doc(`videos/${videoUid}`)
      .set({ likes: incrementLikes, rating: incrementRating }, { merge: true });
  });

exports.onLikeDeleted = functions.firestore
  .document(`videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{voteUid}`)
  .onDelete((snap, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const { videoUid } = context.params;
    const { rating = 0 } = snap.data();

    const incrementLikes = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
    const incrementRating = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(rating * -1);

    return db
      .doc(`videos/${videoUid}`)
      .set({ likes: incrementLikes, rating: incrementRating }, { merge: true });
  });
```

It will increase the `likes` value when someone gives a vite for a video. The `likes` fields doesn't need to be an array. You will get the number of counts directly.

Comment: ok so lets take step for step fist I have to add 2 functions with just the code you post  Correct ?

Comment: Have you ever worked with firebase cloud functions?

Comment: ah not really... would be thankful if you help with this

Comment: Pls read this https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da and setup your functions based on that instructions. Let me know when you are ready for the next step

Comment: If you don't want to do it with the cloud functions you can use the same code with `increment` on your client side.

Comment: Hey @TarikHuber, I would always do a combination of OP and your approach, so store both the array of UIDs and the `voteCount`. That way you can check if an individual user already linked this document, but for example also get the most liked documents with a query.

Comment: @ TarikHuber Ok so I updated my post  I dont think that the function is correct maybe you can check it I you post is really good but probably to high for my Niveau .

Comment: @TarikHuber does it look so bad hahaahah, im sorry for that ?

Comment: I wrote that before you updated your question ;) I will check it tonight

Comment: Doesn't look bad at all :) Could you tell me under what path you add the likes?

Comment: In the function at the moment thats just placeholder so the path is not correct.  I will update a picture of my firebase so you can see how my firebase looks and then maybe create an 'intelligent' path

Comment: ok I updated it so the likes array was the array that I was using before . And also have to say every user can give a value that I also will later calculate together  of the current video. I will also update may method how I was that doing and the firebase picture of course then probably I dont need the other field like videoid and so on anymore to get access later on the value.. I will update a picture hope then its clearer

Comment: that looks very good but it says Cannot find name 'videoUid' and the same for voteUid and 'storyref' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: Found any solution just asking again just to make sure that your comments don't go away

Comment: Hey it still says Cannot find name 'videoUid' and also shouldn't in the dislike function the increment be -1?

Comment: Yes it should be -1. Can you show me the whole error message you see

Comment: Yea sure I updated my post there you can see the errors

Comment: Can you setup your cloud functions without typescript and make sure that you exactly copy the code from my answer.

Comment: What do you mean without time script what is the can I use else ? If that's too time-consuming then maybe we should take the clien side variant...If theres no disadvantages.

Comment: I mean TypeScript. It would be for you as neginner much easier for you to work without Types.

Comment: But I wanna know what's wrong for learning . I opened a new question for that lets see if some can help and then I will tell you the result

Comment: Oh sorry I should honestly showing you the question because you probably the answer to heres my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421204/how-to-set-up-firestore-function-using-typescript

Comment: Hey tarik do you found any solution ?

Comment: I updated my code in that way im getting no error any more . What would say how that looks ? Do you even know how to create function with tyoescript?

Comment: Ah yes. Didn't notice the `$` in the trigger path. Sorry for that. Is it working now?

Comment: before deploying the functions please check the other changes I marked them. So I can deploy it like it looks at the moment.

Comment: I checked it. You can write it like this `return db
      .doc(`videos/${videoUid}`)
      .set({ likes: increment }, { merge: true });` You can return that directly. No need to store it in a variable. You can copy again the code from my answer.

Comment: ok but what's with voteUid that never used iniside this     const { videoUid, voteUid } = context.params;  Thats never read

Comment: That is just a warning and not an error. But yes we can remove it.

Comment: how to fix that issue   6 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

Comment: What errors and warning do you get with the newest code?

Comment: Omg finally I was getting spaces errors again and again but now I deploy it how can I test it now ?

Comment: Just create under this path `videos/{videoUid}/uservotes` something. Doesn't matte what.

Comment: I added to  the already existing uservotes subcollection a empty new document nothing happened

Comment: Try to set the value of `likes` to 0 and at least add a document that has some data in it. It also can take some time to se changes because the functions would have a cold start.

Comment: Ok i See the likes that looks good but how do I check now if a user already liked a video instead of im doing it at the moment

Comment: So how do should my like method look now and fo I still need to at the array for the users?

Comment: You can use a very easy trick. Store the uservotes under the path `videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/${userUid}` so if a user already created a vote for a video we use his UID and if he tries it again he would not write a new doc but override the old one. That overriding would not trigger the function ;)

Comment: Your code is already made like that so you don't need to change anything.

Comment: ok so while im testing it on the real devise got 2 last question. The first one I updated my like method so you can see I only need to save the rating in uservotes doc . My question about that is how can I calculate them together easily and again delete the value of  of one doc when deleting the document ? If you want I can open a new question for that lets just clear this and then I will hopefully asking your the last question.

Comment: To this point 100 times big thanks I m really thankful for that

Comment: I have updated the answer. It stores the amount of votes in `likes` and the sum of rates in `rates`. That way you have the number of likes, the total sum of rates and with both of them you can get the average rate ;)

Comment: Uff  you probably not from this earth..... but just take a step back haha I have to check if user already liked the video because I want that he just only can like one video one time how to solve that That I was checking with the method before ?

Comment: Also im using this for  if user liked I show his rating and if he dont liked than he can liked

Comment: You can check if he already liked the video by getting the path where you store use uservote `videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{userUid}` and just check if it's `null` or has some value.

Comment: It seems that this check not work I updated my post check the latest post theres for example how im using it and its always giving me the yellow star for the current user but the list is empty so nobody votes

Comment: You need to use a `StreamBuilder`. You can't get the value synchronously like that. Let's move that to another question if you like to keep this one clear.

Comment: Yes sure I already created the stream just need to check now if that document exist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433349/how-to-get-a-stream-of-firebase-collection

Comment: Have you checked it ?

Comment: Hey tarik i solved it but maybe you can again help with the functions probably it will be easier when you help instead of somebody else because you know the code heres the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442198/how-to-create-functions-in-firebase

Comment: I think you have there a very good answer. Let me know if you need furtehr help.