# How to create functions in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im using a counter function in firebase. What the function does is add counter for how many people liked that video and also a counter for how many votes these people giving. So for example . User A liked the video with giving 3 of 5 stars. Then the function is adding to the like plus1 and to the user rating field plus3 and then I have also this delete function where its calculating minus 3 stars and minus 1like. What I want now is improve the function with also calculating for one user a counter of how many videos he uploaded and how many stars he generated . For example user a uploads 5 videos and they have 20 likes with a total of 30 stars and then also when one user dislike his video again calculate it minus.

Heres my functions:

```
exports.onLikeCreated = functions.firestore
    .document("videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{voteUid}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const db = admin.firestore();
      const {videoUid} = context.params;
      const {rating = 0} = snap.data();
      const incrementLikes = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
      const incrementRating = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(rating);
      return db
          .doc(`videos/${videoUid}`)
          .set({likes: incrementLikes, rating: incrementRating}, {merge: true});
    });
exports.onLikeDeleted = functions.firestore
    .document("videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{voteUid}")
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
      const db = admin.firestore();
      const {videoUid} = context.params;
      const {rating = 0} = snap.data();
      const incrementLikes = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
      const incrementRating = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(rating * -1);
      return db
          .doc(`videos/${videoUid}`)
          .set({likes: incrementLikes, rating: incrementRating}, {merge: true});
    });
```

So again my functions working perfectly . What i want now is adding 2 fcuntions as new funtions or if its also works just update my already existing functions with 2 counters the first for every like of every  video from the same user . And the other for the rating of all videos (of the same user )together calculated. But if somebody disliked it, then it should also update the calculated rating value and the video counter if
videoiwner deleted one video.
Also i should say When a user liked then he gives for example 3 stars and thats the rating . I need the ratings calculated together and also the like . For example first user liked post with giving 3 stars.
Then like counter should be 1 and rating should be 3. Then second user liked the same post and giving 5 stars. like counter should be updated to 2 and rating to 8 . The functionality should be excatly the same as the funtions that i already use .Just instead of creating a like counter and rating counter for a singel video. Creating a like counter and rating counter of all videos of the same user .

I wanna save the new 2 counters or funtions inside this path "meinprofilsettings/{uid}". There already exist user data that will make it easy to get access , if its not possible then maybe in a subcoleltion of that Heres how the database looks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you rephrase the question?
What part of the code do you want to change and what part of the database do you want to change?

Comment: hey i tried to explain a bit better please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you want to keep track of all total likes and total rating collectively gained by a user from all the videos.
You can increment that value in the meinprofilsettings and keep incrementing it when a video gets a like and and decrement by the like is removed.

```
exports.onLikeCreated = functions.firestore
    .document("videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{voteUid}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const { videoUid } = context.params;
        const { rating = 0 } = snap.data();
        const incrementLikes = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
        const incrementRating = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(rating);
        const userId = (await db.doc(`videos/${videoUid}`).get()).data().userId
        return Promise.all([
            db.doc(`videos/${videoUid}`).set({ likes: incrementLikes, rating: incrementRating }, { merge: true }),
            db.doc(`meinprofilsettings/${userId}`).update({ totalLikes: incrementLikes, totlaRating: incrementRating })
        ])
    });
```

You'll need to know the user Id who has uploaded the video so I have fetched the user document there and then increment the value at both places.

When it comes to decrementing the values, follow the same:

```
exports.onLikeDeleted = functions.firestore
    .document("videos/{videoUid}/uservotes/{voteUid}")
    .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const { videoUid } = context.params;
        const { rating = 0 } = snap.data();
        const decrementLikes = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
        const decrementRating = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(rating * -1);
        const userId = (await db.doc(`videos/${videoUid}`).get()).data().userId
        return Promise.all([
            db.doc(`videos/${videoUid}`).set({ likes: decrementLikes, rating: decrementRating }, { merge: true }),
            db.doc(`meinprofilsettings/${userId}`).update({ totalLikes: decrementLikes, totlaRating: decrementRating })
        ])
    });
```

Let me know if there are any further queries.

Comment: Yes I think you understand it correctly and I updated a picture of my videos collection so you can see how the videos collection looks . I t has a uid field and thats the uid of the user that uploaded the video. Also im getting an error that says Object is possibly undefined  to this line (await db.doc(`videos/${videoUid}`).get()).data()

Comment: @awdfrffe are you using Typescript? Just add a question mark like this `?.data()?`

Comment: i trie still the same

Comment: maybe it should be async ?

Comment: @awdfrffe ah yes, I forgot to add async in 2nd function.

Comment: no Problem where I should add it exactly ?

Comment: @awdfrffe ` .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {`

Comment: Yep but what is with the other problem Object is possibly undefined ?

Comment: I change the picture so you cans ee that one

Comment: @awdfrffe share screenshot with whole code so I can see where the issue is

Comment: @awdfrffe please add the question marks as told earlier

Comment: I add it like that (await db.doc(`videos/${videoUid}`).get())?.data().userId it says the same

Comment: @awdfrffe `(await db.doc(\`videos/${videoUid}\`).get()).data()?.userId` this hides the error for me

Comment: OK I tried the error is away I deployed it but it dont work . I wait for 5 minutes. Do you know which uid I wanna use ? I wanna use the uid in the videos doc and saved the data in the meinptofilsettings collectionwhere the uid is equal to the uid from the video... Hope you can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232115/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-awdfrffe).

Comment: hey sorry I dont see the message. Yea sure I updated the code with 2 pictures cannot send inside this chat the pictures please check

Comment: So the first method works just that that you implenented not working maybe this info helps to solving it

Comment: @awdfrffe what first method r u referring to? Have you replaced the field names correctly?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding I copy you howle code and delete the old functions. IN your code still the old method work just the newseast that your try to implement not work

Comment: ok maybe I should try set instead of update I will try it and let you know the result

Comment: ok this looks different now I have a result but it saves the doc as a new doc in f"meinprofilsettings" collection I update a picture so you can see how it looks

Comment: @awdfrffe `const userId = (await db.doc(\`videos/${videoUid}\`).get()).data()?.uid`  try changing field name to uid Here? I didn't knew your db structure so I has used userId as field name

Comment: Would you maybe help me with another function you now already how my database looks I think it will be easier if you help me instead of explaining everything again

Comment: heres the question maybe you can help.  .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453051/how-to-create-functions-for-following-counter-in-flutter